# telerik web mvc grid serializeData method throws exception

Tags: serialization, grid, telerik-mvc

i have telerik mvc grid in my mvc page. when i try to serialize data using serializeData

it throws the javscript exception as "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".
and also when i view the value of the serializedata method in quickwatch  is undefined.
i think i am missing some javascript reference for teh serialize data. can any one help me in tracking the error

```
function submitchanges(e)
{
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");

//throws exception in below code
var result = grid.serializeData(data,"updated");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the serializeData client side method is available only when the editable configuration is specified for the grid.
i added the belwo snippet to the grid and to get the serializeData()

```
.Editable(editing =>
                {

                    editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell);
                    //editing.TemplateName("CtrlCreatePreAllocation").DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false);
                })
```